# Why I got my local address when visit my server by nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm very confused about why I always get my local page when I visit my server.
[image: This is my server nginx.conf]

[image: I always get this page.]

Is there any errors in my nginx.conf?

Comment: You need to enable logs:
`error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;`
`access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;`
and try to visit: `http://www.dbgsoftware.tech/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by set some headers as below.

```
proxy_set_header Host $host; 
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```